# Asking advice for a animation like the flatworm

Tags: animation

This is the reference video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_GC5Swk0JA
Here is my model, and I want to animate the foot like the reference.
What do you think the best approach is? I tried using a vertex group displacement map but couldn't get the same effect.
Even if I change the noise size, it just doesn't look the same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the movement is quite sinusoidal, you can use a wave modifier.

Set a vertex group to limit its influence to the desired vertices.

In my example the default values, but you can play to tweak the effect.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @josh sanfelici
The wave deformer looked promising, so I tested it out, and moving the starting point to the X-axis and changing the mesh to a circle looked more closely to the reference. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jl2jot2oav0rcs/2023-04-12_08-25-10.mp4?dl=0

But I'm still not getting the twirl effect at the edge...How do you think I could do that?